# Scaling workers for 10M+/day job queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, queue, message-queue, amazon-sqs

We'd like to upgrade our PHP-based AWS SQS queue worker architecture because we're handling 10M+ jobs per day and the infrastructure is getting expensive.

Our jobs use hardly any memory, but can run for 5-10 seconds each due to slow HTTP responses.

Could anyone recommend languages, approaches or tools that either support running dozens of workers on the same machine simultaneously, or can execute dozens of jobs simultaneously very efficiently?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the bottleneck is in HTTP requests, you should consider using node.js. It makes it very easy to program your code so it runs asynchronously. I assume in your current implementation the HTTP requests are blocking the CPU thread. This is inefficient, because the CPU could do something else *while* it is waiting for the request to complete and then it can parse the results. This is almost trivial in node.js and the excellent [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library.

An asynchronous implementation could speed your program up a factor of 10-100 or maybe even more. Especially if the "waiting for HTTP request" takes a lot more time than actual computations. Use a fleet of micro or nano instances, node.js (or javascript in general) is a single threaded language, so normally you don't need multiple cores.

Another approach would be to attach the SNS service to SQS and set up a Lambda function that parses the ticket. See this page for an intro in [AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html). Maybe you have peak days and low days, then this approach should be more cost-effective. When the load is evenly distributed, AWS Lambda is more expensive than EC2.

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain who you'd use the async library in this case? I assume we use Node.js's cluster to start multiple workers on the same machine and then use the async library on those workers?

Comment: You can get a batch of tickets using the SQS batch API call and then use the `async.each` function on all the tickets. It will start downloading at the same time and process them once the HTTP request is finished. You can use micro instances because node.js uses only 1 core. You can also take a multicore instance and then launch multiple instances of your code, but I recommend many single core machines instead (more control)

Answer (score 1):

I've run similar systems, with 30-200+ copies of PHP CLI-based workers across a number of machines. I started them up with Supervisord, where there is a 'numprocs' configuration that says how many of that particular program to start. You can have several such configuration groups.

In terms of optimising also for cost, consider 'spot instances' to reduce the price per hour, per machine. In order to get each system running as quickly as possible, you'll need to ensure that they are pre-setup with all the installed software and configurations they need.

Comment: Thanks! So you run 20-200 workers on the same machine simultaneously? Are you using any particular worker?